# C++ Socket Part-3

Tags: c++, http, socket

In my ongoing attempts to become a better blog writer I have some written some more code that needs reviewing.

Full Source: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/Examples/tree/master/Version3
First Article: http://lokiastari.com/posts/SocketProtocols/

This is an extension to my previous work on Sockets and wraps the socket in a protocol. So that messages can be placed on the stream using the correct protocol. This is the HTTP version.

##Protocol.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_SOCKET_PROTOCOL_H
#define THORSANVIL_SOCKET_PROTOCOL_H

#include <string>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Socket
    {

class DataSocket;
class Protocol
{
    protected:
        DataSocket&     socket;
    public:
        Protocol(DataSocket& socket);
        ~Protocol();

        virtual void sendMessage(std::string const& url, std::string const& message)    = 0;
        virtual void recvMessage(std::string& message)                                  = 0;
};

    }
}

#endif
```

##Protocol.cpp

```
#include "Protocol.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Socket;

Protocol::Protocol(DataSocket& socket)
    : socket(socket)
{}

Protocol::~Protocol()
{}
```

##ProtocolHTTP.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_SOCKET_PROTOCOL_HTTP_H
#define THORSANVIL_SOCKET_PROTOCOL_HTTP_H

#include "Protocol.h"
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Socket
    {

enum RequestType {Response, Head, Get, Put, Post, Delete};

class ProtocolHTTP: public Protocol
{
    struct BufferRange
    {
        char*       inputStart;
        std::size_t inputLength;
        std::size_t totalLength;
        BufferRange(std::vector<char>& buffer)
            : inputStart(&buffer[0])
            , inputLength(0)
            , totalLength(0)
        {}
        void swap(BufferRange& rhs) noexcept
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(inputStart,  rhs.inputStart);
            swap(inputLength, rhs.inputLength);
            swap(totalLength, rhs.totalLength);
        }
    };
    static constexpr char const* endOfLineSeq = "\r\n";
    static constexpr std::size_t bufferSize   = 4096;
    std::vector<char>           bufferData;
    BufferRange                 bufferRange;

    protected:
        char const*   begin()   const   {return bufferRange.inputStart;}
        char const*   end()     const   {return bufferRange.inputStart + bufferRange.inputLength;}

        virtual RequestType getRequestType() const = 0;

        void        putMessageData(std::string const& item);
        std::size_t getMessageData(char* localBuffer, std::size_t size);

        virtual int         getMessageStartLine() = 0;
        std::size_t getMessageHeader(int responseCode);
        void        getMessageBody(std::size_t bodySize, std::string& message);

        std::size_t getMessageDataFromStream(char* buffer, std::size_t size);
        std::size_t getMessageDataFromBuffer(char* localBuffer, std::size_t size);

    public:
        void recvMessage(std::string& message)                               override;
        ProtocolHTTP(DataSocket& socket);

};

class HTTPServer: public ProtocolHTTP
{
    private:
        int         getMessageStartLine() override;
        RequestType getRequestType() const override {return Response;}
    public:
        using ProtocolHTTP::ProtocolHTTP;
        void sendMessage(std::string const& url, std::string const& message) override;
};

class HTTPClient: public ProtocolHTTP
{
    private:
        int         getMessageStartLine() override;
        virtual std::string const& getHost() const = 0;
    public:
        using ProtocolHTTP::ProtocolHTTP;
        void sendMessage(std::string const& url, std::string const& message) override;
};

class HTTPPost: public HTTPClient
{
    std::string host;
    private:
        RequestType getRequestType() const override {return Post;}
        std::string const& getHost() const override {return host;}
    public:
        HTTPPost(std::string const& host, DataSocket& socket)
            : HTTPClient(socket)
            , host(host)
        {}
};


    }
}

#endif
```

##ProtocolHTTP.cpp

```
#include "ProtocolHTTP.h"
#include "Socket.h"
#include "Utility.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <exception>

/*
 * If it is not reading the body it buffers the data internally.
 *
 * Status/Header Lines:
 * ====================
 * When reading the status or headers it will return a single line at a time from
 *      getMessageData()
 *
 * It will prefer to use the internal buffer only reading from the socket when
 * required.
 *
 * Body:
 * ====================
 * Will read data directly into the user provided buffer. If part of the body
 * is in the internal buffer it will be first copied to the user provided buffer
 * before a call to the socket is made for more data.
 *
 * Note:
 * ====================
 * This class assumes the socket connection will be reused as a result it will
 * maintain the input buffer between requests in case part of the next message
 * has been read.
 * BUT: Currently the sendMessage() for both client and server
 *      will close the socket with the call to socket.putMessageClose()
 *
 */

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Socket;


ProtocolHTTP::ProtocolHTTP(DataSocket& socket)
    : Protocol(socket)
    , bufferData(bufferSize)
    , bufferRange(bufferData)
{}

/*
 * The functions to send a message using the HTTP Protocol
 *      sendMessage
 *          putMessageData
 *              socket
 */
void HTTPClient::sendMessage(std::string const& url, std::string const& message)
{
    // The Message Method
    switch(getRequestType())
    {
        case Head:   putMessageData(buildStringFromParts("HEAD ",   url.c_str(), " HTTP/1.1\r\n"));   break;
        case Get:    putMessageData(buildStringFromParts("GET ",    url.c_str(), " HTTP/1.1\r\n"));   break;
        case Put:    putMessageData(buildStringFromParts("PUT ",    url.c_str(), " HTTP/1.1\r\n"));   break;
        case Post:   putMessageData(buildStringFromParts("POST ",   url.c_str(), " HTTP/1.1\r\n"));   break;
        case Delete: putMessageData(buildStringFromParts("DELETE ", url.c_str(), " HTTP/1.1\r\n"));   break;
        default:
            throw std::logic_error(buildStringFromParts("ProtocolHTTP::", __func__, ": unsupported message type requested"));
    }


    // The Message Headers
    putMessageData("Content-Type: text/text\r\n");
    putMessageData(buildStringFromParts("Content-Length: ", message.size(), "\r\n"));
    putMessageData(buildStringFromParts("Host: ", getHost(), "\r\n"));
    putMessageData("User-Agent: ThorsExperimental-Client/0.1\r\n");
    putMessageData("Accept: */*\r\n");
    putMessageData("\r\n");

    // The Message Body
    putMessageData(message);
    socket.putMessageClose();
}

/*
 * Just Read the status line.
 * Validate it has the correct format and retrieve the status code.
 * As this may affect the size of the body.
 */
int HTTPClient::getMessageStartLine()
{
    getMessageData(nullptr, 0);

    char    space1       = '\0';
    char    space2       = '\0';
    char    backslashR   = '\0';
    char    backslashN   = '\0';
    int     responseCode = 0;
    char    responseDescription[1024];
    int     count = std::sscanf(begin(), "HTTP/1.1%c%d%c%1023[^\r\n]%c%c",
                                &space1,
                                &responseCode,
                                &space2,
                                responseDescription,
                                &backslashR,
                                &backslashN);
    if (count != 6 || space1 != ' ' || space2 != ' ' || backslashR != '\r' || backslashN != '\n' || responseCode < 100 || responseCode >= 600)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ProtocolHTTP::", __func__, ": Invalid HTTP Status Line:",
                                 " count(6)=", count,
                                 " space1(32)=", static_cast<int>(space1),
                                 " space2(32)=", static_cast<int>(space2),
                                 " backslashR(10)=", static_cast<int>(backslashR),
                                 " backslashN(13)=", static_cast<int>(backslashN),
                                 " responseCode=", responseCode,
                                 "Line: >", std::string(begin(), end()), "<"));
    }
    return responseCode;
}

/*
 * The functions to send a message using the HTTP Protocol
 *      sendMessage
 *          putMessageData
 *              socket
 */
void HTTPServer::sendMessage(std::string const&, std::string const& message)
{
    putMessageData("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");

    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);

    // The Message Headers
    putMessageData(buildStringFromParts("Date: ", std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z"), "\r\n"));
    putMessageData("Server: ThorsExperimental-Server/0.1\r\n");
    putMessageData(buildStringFromParts("Content-Length: ", message.size(), "\r\n"));
    putMessageData("Content-Type: text/text\r\n");
    putMessageData("\r\n");

    // The Message Body
    putMessageData(message);
    socket.putMessageClose();
}

int HTTPServer::getMessageStartLine()
{
    getMessageData(nullptr, 0);

    char    command[32];
    char    url[4096];
    char    version[32];
    char    space1;
    char    space2;
    char    backslashR;
    char    backslashN;
    int     count = std::sscanf(begin(), "%s%c%s%c%s%c%c",
                                command,
                                &space1,
                                url,
                                &space2,
                                version,
                                &backslashR,
                                &backslashN);
    if (count != 7 || space1 != ' ' || space2 != ' ' || backslashR != '\r' || backslashN != '\n' || strcmp(version, "HTTP/1.1") != 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ProtocolHTTP::", __func__, ": Invalid HTTP Request Line:",
                                 " count(7)=", count,
                                 " space1(32)=", static_cast<int>(space1),
                                 " space2(32)=", static_cast<int>(space2),
                                 " backslashR(10)=", static_cast<int>(backslashR),
                                 " backslashN(13)=", static_cast<int>(backslashN),
                                 " version(HTTP/1.1)=", version,
                                 " Line: >", std::string(begin(), end()), "<"));
    }
    return 200;
}

void ProtocolHTTP::putMessageData(std::string const& item)
{
    socket.putMessageData(item.c_str(), item.size());
}
/*
 * The functions to get a message using the HTTP Protocol
 *      recvMessage
 *          getMessageStartLine
 *          getMessageHeader
 *          getMessageBody
 *
 *      getMessageData
 *          getMessageDataFromBuffer
 *          getMessageDataFromStream
 *              socket
 */
void ProtocolHTTP::recvMessage(std::string& message)
{
    int         responseCode = getMessageStartLine();
    std::size_t bodySize     = getMessageHeader(responseCode);
    getMessageBody(bodySize, message);
}

/*
 * Read the headers for the stream.
 * Read each header in a loop (looking for the '\r\n' sequence.
 *
 * Do some validation on the input and calculate the size
 * of the message body based on the headers.
 */
std::size_t ProtocolHTTP::getMessageHeader(int responseCode)
{
    char        backslashR       = '\0';
    char        backslashN       = '\0';
    bool        hasIdentity      = false;
    bool        hasContentLength = false;
    bool        hasMultiPart     = false;
    std::size_t contentLength = 0;

    char const* begOfRange = nullptr;
    char const* endOfRange = nullptr;
    while(getMessageData(nullptr, 0))
    {
        begOfRange = bufferRange.inputStart;
        endOfRange = bufferRange.inputStart + bufferRange.inputLength;
        if (bufferRange.inputLength <= 2)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (!std::equal(endOfRange - 2, endOfRange, endOfLineSeq))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(buildStringFromParts("ProtocolHTTP::", __func__, ": Header line not terminated by empty line"));
        }
        if (std::find(begOfRange, endOfRange, ':') == endOfRange)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(buildStringFromParts("ProtocolHTTP::", __func__, ": Header line missing colon(:)"));
        }
        if (std::sscanf(begOfRange, "Transfer-Encoding : identity%c%c", &backslashR, &backslashN) == 2
            && backslashR == '\r' && backslashN == '\n')
        {
            hasIdentity         = true;
        }
        if (std::sscanf(begOfRange, "Content-Length : %lu%c%c", &contentLength, &backslashR, &backslashN) == 3
            && backslashR == '\r' && backslashN == '\n')
        {
            hasContentLength    = true;
        }
        if (std::sscanf(begOfRange, "Content-Type : multipart/byteranges%c%c", &backslashR, &backslashN) == 3
            && backslashR == '\r' && backslashN == '\n')
        {
            hasMultiPart        = true;
        }
    }
    if (bufferRange.inputLength != 2 && !std::equal(begOfRange, endOfRange, endOfLineSeq))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(buildStringFromParts("ProtocolHTTP::", __func__, ": Header list not terminated by empty line"));
    }

    // Use the header fields to work out the size of the body/
    std::size_t bodySize = 0;
    if (responseCode < 200 || responseCode == 204 || responseCode == 304 || getRequestType() == Head)
    {
        bodySize = 0;
    }
    else if (hasIdentity)
    {
        throw std::domain_error(buildStringFromParts("ProtocolHTTP::", __func__, ": Identity encoding not supported"));
    }
    else if (hasContentLength)
    {
        bodySize = contentLength;
    }
    else if (hasMultiPart)
    {
        throw std::domain_error(buildStringFromParts("ProtocolHTTP::", __func__, ": Mult-Part encoding not supported"));
    }
    else
    {
        bodySize = -1;
    }
    return bodySize;
}

/*
 * If we have a `bodySize` of -1 then we read until the stream is closed.
 * Otherwise we read `bodySize` bytes from the stream.
 *
 * Note: A closed connection by the client will stop the read and not generate
 *       any errors, but the string will be resize to the amount of data actually
 *       read from the stream.
 */
void ProtocolHTTP::getMessageBody(std::size_t bodySize, std::string& message)
{
    // The Message Body
    std::size_t maxBodySize = bodySize == static_cast<std::size_t>(-1) ? message.capacity() : bodySize;
    std::size_t messageRead = 0;
    std::size_t readSize;

    // Allow us to use all the capacity of the string.
    message.resize(maxBodySize);
    while((readSize = getMessageData(&message[messageRead], maxBodySize - messageRead)) != 0)
    {
        messageRead += readSize;

        // If we have reached the capacity
        // The resize the string to allow for more data.
        if (messageRead == maxBodySize && bodySize == static_cast<std::size_t>(-1))
        {
            maxBodySize = maxBodySize * 1.5 + 10;
            message.resize(maxBodySize);
        }
    }
    // reset the size to the actual amount read.
    message.resize(messageRead);
}

/*
 * Read Data:
 *  Check to see if there is data in the local buffer and use that.
 *  Otherwise read from the socket.
 *
 * Note:
 * ========
 * If we are reading Status/Header information then `localBuffer`
 * will be set to nullptr and we should read the data into the buffer
 * for manual processing.
 *
 * If we are reading the Body the `localBuffer` points at the buffer
 * passed by the user so we can fill it with the content that is
 * coming from the stream.
 */
std::size_t ProtocolHTTP::getMessageData(char* localBuffer, std::size_t size)
{

    if (bufferRange.totalLength != 0)
    {
        std::size_t result = getMessageDataFromBuffer(localBuffer, size);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bufferRange.inputStart  = &bufferData[0];
    }

    return getMessageDataFromStream(localBuffer, size);
}

std::size_t ProtocolHTTP::getMessageDataFromBuffer(char* localBuffer, std::size_t size)
{
    bufferRange.inputStart  += bufferRange.inputLength;
    bufferRange.totalLength -= bufferRange.inputLength;
    bufferRange.inputLength = 0;

    std::size_t result     = 0;

    if (localBuffer != nullptr)
    {
        result      = std::min(bufferRange.totalLength, size);

        std::copy(bufferRange.inputStart, bufferRange.inputStart + result, localBuffer);
        bufferRange.totalLength -= result;
    }
    else
    {
        auto begOfRange = bufferRange.inputStart;
        auto endOfRange = bufferRange.inputStart + bufferRange.totalLength;
        auto find       = std::search(begOfRange, endOfRange, endOfLineSeq, endOfLineSeq + 2);
        if (find != endOfRange)
        {
            bufferRange.inputLength = find + 2 - bufferRange.inputStart;
            result  = bufferRange.inputLength;
        }
        else
        {
            // We found some of a header or the method in the buffer
            // But it was not the whole line. So move this fragment to
            // the beginning of the buffer and return 0 to indicate
            // that not a complete line was read. This will result in
            // a call to getMessageDataFromStream()
            std::copy(begOfRange, endOfRange, &bufferData[0]);
            bufferRange.inputStart = &bufferData[0];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

std::size_t ProtocolHTTP::getMessageDataFromStream(char* localBuffer, std::size_t size)
{
    char*           buffer    = localBuffer ? localBuffer : bufferRange.inputStart;
    std::size_t     dataRead  = localBuffer ? 0           : bufferRange.totalLength;
    std::size_t     dataMax   = localBuffer ? size        : bufferSize - (bufferRange.inputStart - &bufferData[0]);
    char*           lastCheck = buffer + (dataRead ? dataRead - 1 : 0);
    BufferRange&    br        = bufferRange;

    return socket.getMessageData(buffer + dataRead, dataMax, [localBuffer, &br, buffer, &lastCheck, dataRead](std::size_t readSoFar)
    {
        // Reading the Body.
        // There is no reason to stop just read as much as possible.
        if (localBuffer != nullptr)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Reading the status line or one of the headers.
        // So once we have a line in the buffer stop reading and processes it.
        auto totalDataRead = dataRead + readSoFar;
        auto find = std::search(lastCheck, buffer + totalDataRead, endOfLineSeq, endOfLineSeq + 2);
        if (find != buffer + totalDataRead)
        {
            br.inputLength = find + 2 - buffer;
            br.totalLength += readSoFar;
            return true;
        }
        lastCheck = find - 1;
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite nit picky, but I don't like the way that you've got multiple classes in the same file.  Whilst the underlying protocol is shared between the Client & Server, they are distinct and having the classes in the same file makes it difficult to follow (if I search I always have to check the owner of the method I'm in rather than relying on the file).  This is made worse by the fact that you haven't grouped the implementation for each class together.  If you *really* want to do this, then at least group the methods for each class together.  At the moment, the `ProtocolHTTP` constructor is at the top of the file, followed by the Client methods, then the Server methods and then the rest of the ProtocolHTTP methods.

---

I don't really understand how your HTTPClient can be used successfully.  In my head, from a client perspective HTTP is a send then receive protocol.  You send a request to the server, which will then send you a response to receive.  The HTTPClient::sendMessage method calls putMessageClose, which shuts down the socket, so I would expect any receives after this point to fail.  You've hinted that this is expected behaviour in your comment block at the top of the file, but it still feels wrong.

Comment: I like nit picking. So no issues there. I agree my layout could be much more organized. I will address that.

Comment: `putMessageClose()` closes the write side of the socket (not the read side) so that the server knows we have reached the end of request. The server can still respond and the client. Maybe I should re-name that.

Answer (score 1):

You have `virtual` methods in `Protocol` class. That is either a mistake or intention to use it in some class hierarchy. If the latter is true you very probably want Protocol destructor to be `virtual` as well.

---

Keeping reference as a member might lead to nasty surprises if the object it points to goes out of scope.

```
    DataSocket&     socket;
public:
    Protocol(DataSocket& socket);
```

Maybe using `str::shared_ptr` (or `std::weak_ptr` depending on your design, dependencies, error handling strategy etc.) for having access to shared resource might be better.

---

```
char*       inputStart;
// ...
BufferRange(std::vector<char>& buffer)
    : inputStart(&buffer[0])
```

This might also lead to troubles once the vector you've initialized `inputStart` member with is destructed. I would personally try to have interface as foolproof as possible and double so regarding memory management.